# array_intersect giving performance issue in presto

Tags: presto

I have a query running in presto which has array_intersect condition. This is taking around 5 hrs to run. If I remove the array_intersect then it is taking less than an hour.

```
CARDINALITY(ARRAY_INTERSECT(links, ARRAY['504949547', '504949616', '515604515', '515604526', '515604527', '515604528'])) > 0
```

Can anyone please let me know how to improve the performance. Have to get it less than 5 mins.

Have tried enabling the spill disk but it didnt help. Input data size is around 1TB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_intersect` materializes the result (the intersection), whereas the only thing you are checking is the membership of certain predefined elements.
In this case I'd recommend using [`any_match`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#any_match) instead.

```sql
any_match(links, e -> e IN ('504949547', '504949616', ...))
```

If you're using Presto versions that doesn't have [`any_match`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#any_match), you can use [`reduce`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#reduce):

```sql
reduce(
    links, -- array to reduce
    false, -- initial state
    (s, e) -> s OR e IN ('504949547', '504949616', ...), -- reduction function
    s -> s) -- output function
```

> Have tried enabling the spill disk but it didnt help.

Note: [In Presto, spill is supported for certain operators](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/admin/spill.html#supported-operations) (most of the Joins, Aggregations, Order By, Window functions). It is not applicable to scalar functions operating on `ARRAY`s. Also, you should not expect spill to *increase performance*. It can only *reduce memory footprint*, at the *cost* of performance.

Comment: Hi @piotrfindeisen, thanks for the quick response. I'm using 0.224 version and I dont find any_match function in this. We are actually AWS EMR and the later version available in AWS is 0.224. Thanks

Comment: btw I invite you to join Presto Community Slack https://prestosql.io/slack.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, I have joined Slack. Thanks again

Comment: I don't see you on Slack, so you might have joined Facebook Presto's slack. 
Please check the slack link @ https://prestosql.io/slack.html